# IPTables rules to Deny ALL traffic for an IP range with CRON

Tags: cron, iptables

I currently have a ClearOS gateway server in transparent proxy mode. It has a lot of great tools but I have some issues preventing me from forcing the use of the web proxy directly which would give the control over scheduling using ACLs....

Long story short. I need to find a way to block ALL traffic for specific IP addresses and IP ranges. I have studied this out and I need to do this through the firewall (IPTables). Ideally, I would like to set up a cron job to swap out the IPTables rules to start and stop all traffic for the specified IP ranges/addresses.

I saw someone who talked about doing this in a forum but they gave no details. They suggested having multiple iptable config files for the different conditions and then using cron to swap them. I am not sure if setting a cron command using an IPTables command to add/remove a rule or set of rules is possible or preffereable. In any case I am a novice at this specifically but I am saavy enough to get in and get my hands dirty....

If you have information on how to do this I thank you in advance. I am not looking for alternative methods at this point as I have looked at just about all of them. Going with the firewall and cron is my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing this up for those who may come across this issue.... I was able to solve it with some help from the ClearOS forum and a couple of really helpful guys... Here is the link so I don't have to replicate the entire thread here:

http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,7/func,view/id,46918/